# Standard Notation for Monomial Orderings?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Is there a standard way to denote a particular lexicographic (resp. reverse lexicographic) monomial ordering using subscripts or superscripts? For example, I might want to refer to the lexicographic (resp. reverse lexicographic) ordering on $\mathbb k[X_1,X_2,X_3]$ with the convention that $X_2$ precedes $X_3$ precedes $X_1$. I have seen in $\preceq_{lex}$ (resp. $\preceq_{revlex}$) to denote any lexicographic (resp. reverse lexicographic) monomial ordering---or one where the convention is implied---but I am interested in distinguishing between orderings with different conventions in degree $1$. Right now my best attempt at the example I mentioned is $\preceq_{\overrightarrow{231}}$ (resp. $\preceq_{\overleftarrow{132}}$). Thanks!

Comment: How many such orderings do you plan to use in the same section? It's probably best for the reader if you just use $\preceq$ and explicitly state what you mean. That way there's no confusion, and no unwieldy notation (like $X_2^2 \preceq_{\overrightarrow{231}} X_2X_3$)

Comment: Unfortunately, I do have examples which require me to list several such orderings. However I won't actually have to write expressions directly comparing two monomials as in your example.